# Is there a method to do communication between two components which are not parent and child without using event emitter in angualr?

Tags: angular

In angular we can communication between two components which are parent and child using @input and @output but is there a way to communicate between two components which not parent and child without using event emitter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes, as stated in the documentation, you can in fact make use of [services](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) for component interaction. They don't have to be related (parent-child). Check out the above link for a sample implementation of it.

2) Another way to do it with services would be the following way below, but it will make use of EventEmitter:

```
@Injectable()
export class CommunicationService { 
  isTrigger: boolean = false;
  @Output() change: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  toggle() {
    this.isTrigger = !this.isTrigger;
    this.change.emit(this.isTrigger);
  }

}
```

On the 'parent' component,

```
// somewhere in this component will call the emit() method
.
.
emit() {
  this.communicationService.toggle();
}
```

On the target component,

```
isTrigger: boolean = false
.
.
this.communicationService.change.subscribe(isTrigger => {
  this.isTrigger = isTrigger;
});
```

3) State management. Depending on the complexity of your project, it may be better to use a state management framework such as [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/), as your main components will be much cleaner. If you have worked with React/Redux, this will be very familiar to you. I will only recommend it if your application has a real requirement for it. Otherwise, a combination of Observables/RxJS and EventEmitters will be more than sufficient.

Comment: Ahh thanks. As in the documentation we can make service with a subject and do it. Thanks alot

Comment: You're welcome. Just curious, why do you not want to use EventEmitter? Is there some kind of restriction from your project?

Comment: No no i just wanted to know is there way other than event emitter to communicate between components.

Comment: I see.. Another way I can think of is to make use of the flux architecture. Have you heard of it?

Comment: Ahh yes. But i didnt use it sill.

Comment: I see. You may check it out here: https://ngrx.io/. Depending on the complexity of your project, it may be better to introduce a state layer, as your code will be much cleaner. This is because your main components will no longer have all those component interaction properties.

Comment: Ohh thanks wentjun for telling me about this is new area to study about. I didnt know about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also archive this by using a **subject** from **Rxjs**

1./ Create service

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
 @Injectable()
 export class MessageService {
  public message = new Subject<string>();
  setMessage(value: string) {
    this.message.next(value); //it is publishing this value to all the subscribers 
    that have already subscribed to this message
  }
}
```

2./ Now, inject this service in component1.ts and pass an instance of it to the constructor. Do this for component2.ts too. Use this service instance for passing the value of #message to the service function setMessage

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { MessageService } from '../../service/message.service';
 @Component({
   selector: 'app-home',
   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
 })
export class Component1Component {
constructor(public messageService:MessageService) { }
 setMessage(event) {
   console.log(event.value);
   this.messageService.setMessage(event.value);
 }
}
```

3./ Inside component2.ts, subscribe and unsubscribe (to prevent memory leaks) to the Subject

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from './service/message.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class Component2Component {
 message: string;
 subscription: Subscription;
constructor(public messageService: MessageService) { }
ngOnInit() {
this.subscription = this.messageService.message.subscribe(
  (message) => {
    this.message = message;
  }
 );
}
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
 }
}
```

Comment: Yeah yush thats what we were talking about in the first answer. We can use subjects for the communicatoin. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ohh okay no worries.I did't see the code of subject so i write the answer so in future  other developer may get help from my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

**A solution using Observables.**

```
//message.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MessageService {

  private messageCommand = new Subject<string>();
  messageCommand$ = this.messageCommand.asObservable();

  invokeMessage(msg: string) {
    this.messageCommand.next(msg);
  }
}

//component-one.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from '../services/message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-one',
  templateUrl: './component-one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-one.component.css']
})
export class ComponentOneComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  yourActionMethod() {
    this.messageService.invokeMessage('This is from component one');
  }
}

//component-two.ts

import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from '../services/message.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-two',
  templateUrl: './component-two.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-two.component.css']
})
export class ComponentTwoComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  messageSubscription: Subscription;
  message: string;

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribeToMessageEvents();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.messageSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  subscribeToMessageEvents() {
    this.messageSubscription = this.messageService.messageCommand$.subscribe(
      (msg: string) => {
        this.message = msg;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Here I have used a service class containing an observable of type string.

Then from component-one, a message is published using the invokeMessage method in our message service.

The component which needs to receive the message, in our case component-two should subscribe to the messsageCommand$ in the message service.

> One thing you have to keep in mind is whenever you are subscribing to
>   an observable make sure that you unsubscribe it when the component
>   gets destroyed.

Comment: Ahh yes dilani thats what we are talking about in the above. We can use service with subject. Yeah thats a good point we have to unsubscribe once we have subscribe.