# How to get values from angular custom elements

Tags: angular, custom-element, angular-elements

Im having some angular custom elements. I want to create instance of those and get their model values in its parent component. The input, output methods not helping. Could you please suggest me a way. Thanks in advance.

**Create Custom ELement**

```
const PopupElement = createCustomElement(PopupComponent, {injector});
customElements.define('popup-element', PopupElement);
```

**The custom element is used in a parent element**

```
const popupEl: NgElement & WithProperties<PopupComponent> = document.createElement('popup-element') as any;

popupEl.addEventListener('closed', () => document.body.removeChild(popupEl));

popupEl.message = message;

document.body.appendChild(popupEl);
```

Now i want the parent element to get the new value of message.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: you can use rxjs subject for getting the values. Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252637/is-there-a-method-to-do-communication-between-two-components-which-are-not-paren/55253276#55253276

Comment: What are the "custom elements"?

Comment: your explanation in not enough. can you explain in details with example?

Comment: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).