# Angular passing value through controllers via class extend

Tags: angular, class, extends

I have class that extends another class. For example:

```
export class FirstClass {
    count: number = 0;
    constructor() {}

    get getCount() { return this.count };
    increaseCount() { this.count++ };
}

export class SecondClass extends FirstClass {
    constructor() { super() }
}
```

Template for **FirstClass**:

```
<div> <button (click)="increaseCount">Increase</button> <div>
```

Template for **SecondClass**:

```
<div> {{ getCount }} <div>
```

In the second template, it is always showing 0;
Can anyone explain how can I get value dynamically? 
P.s this two components do not interact with each other. They are absolutely separated from each other.

Comment: you can use subject for these here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252637/is-there-a-method-to-do-communication-between-two-components-which-are-not-paren/55253276#55253276

Comment: no i don't have stackblits

Comment: @YashRami your comment was helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You declared your click callback in wrong way

```
<div> <button (click)="increaseCount">Increase</button> <div>
```

should be

```
<div> <button (click)="increaseCount()">Increase</button> <div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htyyuv